# Unable to create account for installing Oracle Database

Tags: sql, oracle, user-accounts

So I was looking for installing an Oracle 12c database on my Windows 8 laptop, so that I could learn much of SQL(after posting my last question).
I have downloaded all the needed zips. obviously while trying I got error:

```
[INS-30131] Initial setup required for the execution of installer validations failed.


Additional Information:  
 - Framework setup check failed on all the nodes
 - Cause: Cause Of Problem Not Available
 - Action: User Action Not Available
Summary of the failed nodes
hp
 - Version of exectask could not be retrieved from any node
 - Cause: Cause Of Problem Not Available
 - Action: User Action Not Available
```

Well after looking into many posts on SO, I figured out that it needs some hidden User account (C$). I got steps for setting up such a account but unfortunately they are not working for me.

Following the path as: Control Panel>Administrative Tools> Computer Management>Shared.
As mentioned in steps across internet, there is no option for me to create a new account.

Apart from that, I have tried changing my Username and also I have tried using default Administrator account but nothing seems working.

I am pretty sure this is not new so somebody out there must have a solution to this issue. Pls advice...

Answer (score 0):

This is the description of the error, I saw it, but was trying to find an idea how to fix it.

Anyway, I solved it by renaming  the volume group and updating accordingly the fstab and the grub.conf.